# intellisense disappeared in eclipse, how to get it back

Tags: eclipse, intellisense

I don't know what happened but the intellisense just disappeared; how to get it back? I tried creating new projects, rebooting, doesn't help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Did you reset the preferences of default options in '`Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced`', like mentioned in [this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working/908930#908930)

Answer (score 3):

window -> preferences -> editor -> content assist

and check the completion inserts box

Comment: didn't helped, should be something else