# C++ Cascades - Intellisense not present?

Tags: blackberry-10

I am trying to write some C++ code in the momentics IDE with the project type as 'C++ Cascades Application'. To my surprise there's no Intellisense support.

Does anyone know how to enable intellisense with C++?

Comment: Check Intellisense for eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085749/intellisense-dissapeared-in-eclipse-how-to-get-it-back

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely autocomplete available in the Momentics IDE. Just press CTRL+Enter to show the list of available methods/classes etc. Also works in the QML editor for object properties.

Answer (score 0):

The default delay before showing the list is 500ms. In the preferences, search for "Content Assist" and you can configure the delay.