# Why is hover for quick java docs not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have imported a maven project through SVN in my organization. I am not able to see JavaDocs on hovering over any class, method neither is the class or method highlighting so that I can go into the respective implementation. Also, I cannot see javadocs even for core java classes. Whenever, I press Shift + F2, I get error saying, "The resource is not on the build path of a Java Project." 
I have tried the different answers on this forum and others as well. None seems to work. Can anyone help regarding this solution?

UPDATE: Just to add, open call hierarchy is also not working.

Comment: Have you tried right click on project -> Maven -> Download Java Doc ?

Comment: Yes. Didn't work with that.

Comment: If your Maven project has modules, Eclipse will show you a project for the parent project, and a project for each of the modules.  But the files in the parent project will not be "seen" as Java files, since the parent project is just a container for all the modules in it.  You would have to open the same file in the appropriate module project - those will be seen as Java files.

Comment: Right. This works. I just posted this from a separate answer from a different question

Answer (score 0):

Finding a solution for this, I stumbled upon this which solved the problem for me:
Make sure you are not editing the file in maven parent project.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7415743/3662041

I don't have enough points to upvote the above answer. Whoever checks this answer, please upvote the answer mentioned in the link.