# Eclipse error "This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

Has anyone experienced this error before: this happens when I hit CTRL + space, here is the error :

[image]

> This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project.

This is a maven project, mvn eclipse:eclipse doesn't help I mean it compiles and runs just fine just something is wrong and I can't figure out what. I checkouted this project from SVN, it wasn't developed on my PC.

**EDIT**

Not only it does not work but also when I try to open generated classes from target dir I get message `the class file is not on the classpath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this post:

[Eclipse/Java code completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working/908930#908930)

Comment: I found this one on a different page:

"This was an error i got with intellisense/autocompletion in Eclipse. The project needs to be a “Java Project” and not a “Project”, this can be done by doing a new checkout of the code from the “SVN Repositories” view and selecting the project “Wizard” when prompted. I could not find any other way from within Eclipse to create a Java Project and also retrieve the code from SVN/CVS. I suppose you could create a new project and then copy over the appropriate files, but I don’t know if eclipse-svn is smart enough to handle this."

Comment: I was afraid of that, I checked out this with ant with several other projects(like 15 modules and submodules), is there anything I can do now?

Comment: I had the same problem and I only know the way to make a new checkout. I am sorry but tell me if you know a better way.