# Eclipse Intellisense?

Tags: eclipse, intellisense, content-assist

How do I tell Eclipse to automatically make suggestions as I type? I'm looking for a Visual Studio Intellisense-like feature with Resharper.

Currently I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> each time.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You don't have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> * <kbd>space</kbd> but maybe the delay is too big or you don't like the trigger (default is '.'). Go to

> Window -> Preferences ->
>   Java/Editor/Content Assist

And change the settings under *Auto Activation* to your likings.

If this does not work for windows users then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/908930/420613).

Comment: user Kevin Rossi tried to edit to point this (which really is a comment) : "This doesn't work with the Eclipse Juno C/C++ distro"

Comment: Each editor in Eclipse may have its own auto activation triggers--activating on the same characters wouldn't make sense in ever language.

Comment: In Mac it is `ADT -> Preferences -> Java/Editor/Content Assist`

Answer (score 183):

I've get closer to VisualStudio-like behaviour by setting the "Autocomplete Trigger for Java" to

```
.(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

and setting delay to 0.

Now I'd like to realize how to make it autocomplete method name when I press ( as VS's Intellisense does.

Comment: thanks for the tip, thats a little better but still no where near as good as VS!

Comment: Which version of eclipse is this? The "Auto activation triggers for Java" textbox lets me enter only 4 characters.

Comment: This works very well. Much better, since it will actually show local variables and everything now. Thanks! @HappyCoder4U This may not help, but I'm using eclipse 3.7M5.

Comment: you are genius :) no such setting for non-java languages though :(

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! Using Eclipse on Mac (3.6.1) the parameter name is 'Auto activation triggers for Java'

Comment: Not sure why the settings aren't like that by default.  At 200ms delay, it doesn't even seem to work.

Comment: Everything worked but now I get some very irritating behavior: suppose I want to type "private int counter;" I start with private and the autocomplete kicks in with some suggestions (the firt is PrivateCredentialPermission). When I'm done typing private and press "space" PrivateCredentialPermission gets inserted. Any way around this?

Comment: Tony is a pure genius.

Comment: I second on what @VM said. The inclusion of that variable name is rather annoying.

Comment: @VM4 On the "Code Assist Preferences", on "Insertion", check the "Insert common prefixes automatically".

Comment: Great idea! and I help me better understand this eclipse feature.

Comment: See this stack overflow question for some solutions to the space problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297735/stop-spacebar-keypress-from-triggering-autocomplete-in-eclipse

Comment: I added space to the list of my list of triggers.  This lets me do things like "int x = " and immediately, it shows me a list of method names I can invoke if I so choose.

Answer (score 46):

Tony is a pure genius. However to achieve even better auto-completion try setting the triggers to this:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz =.(!+-*/~,[{@#$%^&
```

(specifically aranged in order of usage for faster performance :)

Comment: This method introduces some bugs. For example, if I type in `=`, it would immediately suggest something. If I press space, `= `, it would automatically insert the first match.

Comment: checking Java proposal, Java Type proposal and java non-type proposal and moving them on top in order, worked for me.

Comment: See this stack overflow question for some solutions to the space problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297735/stop-spacebar-keypress-from-triggering-autocomplete-in-eclipse

Comment: All of the special characters will make the Intellisense act screwy except for the period. Basically, if you will ever not want it to Intellisense after a character is typed, you don't want it in this list.

Answer (score 6):

If it's not working even when you already have Code Assist enabled, Eclipse's configuration files are probably corrupt. A solution that worked for me (on Eclipse 3.5.2) was to:

1. Close Eclipse.
2. Rename the workspace directory.
3. Start Eclipse. (This creates a new workspace directory.)
4. Import (with copy) the Java projects from the old workspace.

Comment: Fixed it for me aswell

Comment: Nice Solution, it was really helpful to me, my Eclipse was unable to show intellisense after (.) , I had to use ctrl+space 3 times to show it, Thanks for the nice Solution :-)

Answer (score 5):

I once had the same problem, and then I searched and found this and it worked for me:

I had got some of the boxes unchecked, so I checked them again, then it worked. Just go to

> *Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced*

and check the boxes which you want .

Comment: Also you can arrange the proposals in order of your priority. If it is to show methods and properties related to your identifier, put Java Proposals (Task Specific) first

Answer (score 5):

d3dave's answer is cool. However theGreenGarbage mentioned an issue about it which I too find rather annoying. So here's one that doesn't immediately suggest something after '=' sign and when typing blank space:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.(!+-*/~,[{@#$%^&
```

What I did was simply remove the space and '=' chars from the array :)

Alternatively if you want suggestions when typing blank space, but not after '=' sign:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz .(!+-*/~,[{@#$%^&
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Though, it leads to a bit of lagging.