# Eclipse IDE - how to show class members while typing

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Lets say I have a Class "`Vehicle`"

In netbeans, I can type:

```
Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
```

When i type "v.", I instantly get a list of all the class functions and fields

But in Eclipse, when I type "v." nothing pops up.

Can someone tell me how to enable this option in Eclipse? Also how can I format my code in eclipse?

Edit: When i Press CTRL+Space, after typing "v.", i get a small window that says "No default Proposals"

Comment: Highlight code and press Crtl + i to format

Comment: Are talking about intellisense? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943131/eclipse-intellisense

Comment: See this answer to configure the Auto Complete to be "instant" http://stackoverflow.com/a/4225995/843318

Comment: When you type what you typed (`Vehicle v` and so on), nothing should show up because object v is not created yet. The only 2 things you can do is assign a value (for example by calling `new Vehicle()` like you did), or finish the statement with a semi-colon.

Comment: It is still not working, nothing shows up in default proposals..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse/Java code completion not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code assist is Ctrl-Space.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_editor_keyboard_shortcuts_are_available%3F

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing Ctrl-space.

[Here is a list](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key) of shortcuts. In Eclipse, I believe that Ctrl-Shift-L shows many more.

Comment: When i Press CTRL+Space, after typing "v.", i get a small window that says "No default Proposals"

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working . I vote to close your question as duplicate (I have edited it to add this info)

Answer (score 2):

The default keyboard shortcut to format code is Ctrl-Shift-F.

For preferences regarding content assist, look at Window - Preferences - Java - Editor - Content assist. The popup may appear automatically, or may appear by typing Ctrl - space. You probably don't see anything appearing because the code isn't valid. Make sure to import the Vehicle class (Ctrl - Shift - O).

Comment: When i Press CTRL+Space, after typing "v.", i get a small window that says "No default Proposals"

Comment: You won't see any proposal if Vehicle is not imported, or if you have compilation errors in the class.

Comment: Vehicle is imported, and there are no compilation errors in that Class, and I still do not see the list of methods :(

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to get autocompletion

Answer (score 0):

The default option you have on eclipse is CTRL+SPACE .
You can alter the short cut by 
Go to preferences >General > editor >Keys . There in the left panel you can set whatever shortcut you like . I prefer mostly the default one .