# Working in Cocos2dx, Intellisense in Eclipse not appearing

Tags: eclipse, cocos2d-x

Can anyone tell why intellisense is not appearing in eclipse while making cpp files.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943131/eclipse-intellisense

Comment: sorry mate this didnt help at all since i am working in cocos2dx and i need intellisense to appear while i am coding in c++