# How do I disable this popup or a intellisense in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I want to disable this. It is keep on populating while coding. I am using Eclipse Oxygen version.

Here is the link for the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzV6F.jpg

Comment: Look here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943131/eclipse-intellisense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you would want to do this is beyond my understanding, but anyways..

Uncheck the Combined Hover in Preferences->Java->Editor->Hovers.
[image: The preference for the source/variable hover]