# How to make Spring/Eclipse IntelliSense autocomplete like in Visual Studio?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, visual-studio

I am a .net developer and from last year I started learning Java. But something make me sad, and that is the Java autocomplete IntelliSense. After I choose something from IntelliSense, a method name for example, it put the method name with the default parameter as well. **I don't want that!!!** I want to work like in Visual Studio, just to put there the name and that's it because usually when I do that I already copy paste a line from above and I want to change only the class method name...

How to change how this autocomplete works?

I attached a photo after I choose a method from that object, but that line was copied from above before choosing.


[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one of the following:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while selecting a code completion proposal
- Configure overwrite instead of insert code completion behavior as default:

  1. In *Window > **Preferences: Java > Editor > Content Assist*** in the first section choose ***Completion overwrites***

Answer (score 0):

Your question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943131/eclipse-intellisense). Basically the gist of it:

Eclipse already has its own sort of Intellisense that only gets triggered by a "." by default. You can change the settings under:

Window -> Preferences -> Java/Editor/Content Assist

A problem, if you want the Intellisense to be always active. The "fix" would be to always use "ctrl"+"space" to open the Intellisense GUI. (Or, even better, to add every letter and character to the Intellisense triggers under: Window -> Preferences -> Java/Editor/Content Assist)