# Eclipse intellisense disappeared for particular MXML file (Flex Project)

Tags: eclipse, intellisense

I was trying to replace a container with different types of containers (I commented out the markup for that container and typed in the markup for the other containers). Finally I reverted and removed all the comments, restoring the original container.

Now I'm getting no errors or warnings, but I cannot see the MXML objects in the intellisense when working in the included actionscript file.

For e.g. when I typed "dg" + CTRL-space I dont' see "dgSalesData".

However, I know the IDE recognizes the object, for if I call a non-existent method on the object (e.g. dgSalesData.callNonExistentMethod()) it gives a compiler error.

What can I do to restore the intellisense?

I already checked out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working/908930#908930). All the boxes are checked in  'Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced'. Moreover, all other inluded actionscript files can see objects in their MXML counterparts.

I think it's related to formatting the MXML markup, because I've seen a loss of intellisense before. I used to use a plugin called "Pretty Print Command" that would format my code like in VS. Then I noticed that when I use it intellisense sometimes gets lost, so I stopped using it.

EDIT: Wow, I just noticed that the IDE has it's own formatting option. I don't know I missed it:) However, after letting the IDE format the MXML and re-building the intellisense still won't show any of the MXML objects.

Does anyone have an idea how I can restore the intellisense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible. I made another copy of the actionscript file and included that file. This restored the intellisense, though the VSS history for the file is now split into two. A very dirty solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I made a copy of the MXML file and the included actionscript file. I then deleted the local copies of the MXML and actionscript files and renamed the copy to the original. I then simply re-checked it back to source safe.

Comment: That's weird. It works when the actionscript file has a different name (e.g. SalesData2.as). When I rename it back to SalesData.as and change the name of the include file in the MXML file to SalesData.as, it loses the intellisense!! What is going on here?? Is the project file corrupted? If so, what can I do? If the file is renamed I will lose all the history in VSS!:(