# Ctrl Space Not Working in Eclipse Helios on Win 7

Tags: eclipse

I have shifted by Dev Env recently to Eclipse Helios on Windows 7. After that the Ctrl + Space Content Assist feature is not working. I found out that that key option is utilized by Language Settings. I have tried disabling it. But it still doesn't work in Eclipse.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try restarting eclipse with -clean param

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working/908930#908930 help?

Comment: @Chakra - It didn't help @Vonc - I guess that is something different. I am not even getting "No Default Proposals". In my case nothing happens after pressing Ctrl+Space. Right now I have set a different short cut for the same and solved.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986750/ctrl-space-not-working-for-content-assist-on-eclipse

Answer (score 21):

Configure Eclipse’s content assist, go “Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced“. Make sure “Other Java Proposals” is ticked.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/content-assist-ctrl-space-is-not-working-eclipse/

Comment: This is not an Eclipse problem, but Windows Office which installs a tool that hijacks Ctrl-Space.

Answer (score 6):

> In my case nothing happens after pressing Ctrl+Space. Right now I have set a different short cut for the same and solved

Check your "Keys" preferences: maybe the Content Assist" shortcut has been overridden by another command which would *also* use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
That could happen with the installation of a new plugin, coming with its own set of commands and shortcuts: the [bug 303894](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=303894) for the [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) plugin is a good example.

Comment: No. There are no such conflicts

Comment: @dhanush: And yet a different shortcut for "Content Assist" works? And did you try switching to a new workspace?

Comment: yes a different short cut works. I tried a new Workpsace also, but no luck.

Comment: The conflict is wich the standard key sequence to enter some international characters like non latin characters.  The proper way is to us another sequence than Ctrl-Space

Answer (score 3):

You probably have another application (in systray) that uses Ctrl+Space for something else. In my case I have a small utility which when I press Ctrl+Space makes the active window on top.

The **solution** for you would be to **(1)** exit that application which overrides the keys or **(2)** in Eclipse change Ctrl+Space to some other set of keys.

Comment: This is what I was using http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13784/keep-a-window-on-top-with-a-handy-autohotkey-script/

Comment: @Amil I use the same thing. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

This was solution for me to get rid of windows key shortcuts:

1. Go to Start > Type in regedit and start it
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Input Method/Hot Keys
3. Select the key named: 00000070 for the Chinese (Traditional) IME -
   Ime/NonIme Toggle hotkey 00000010 for the Chinese (Simplified) IME -
   Ime/NonIme Toggle hotkey
4. In the right sub-window, there are three subkeys. Key Modifiers
   designate Alt/Ctrl/Shift/etc and is set to Ctrl (02c00000). Virtual
   Key designates the finishing key and is set to Space (20000000).
5. Change the first byte in Key Modifiers from 02 to 00
6. Change the first byte in Virtual Key from 20 to FF
7. Log off and log back on. I don't think it's necessary to restart.
8. Do not change the Hot keys for input languages in Control Panel,
   unless you want to do this all over again.

https://superuser.com/questions/327479/ctrl-space-always-toggles-chinese-ime-windows-7

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a similar problem in Eclipse Juno (version 4.2.0).

Since you have already tried [Eclipse/Java code completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/908489/509840), I would check to see if there are any key conflicts. Go to Window -> Preference -> General -> Keys. In the filter box, replace the light gray "type filter text" with the word "Content"; the first item should be "Content Assist." Select it. It should have nothing in the Conflicts box in the lower right-hand portion of the screen.

If you have no conflicts, then it is likely that there is another program, outside of Eclipse, that is binding to Ctrl + Space.

I worked around this with an ugly solution. I copied the Content Assist. In the Binding field, I entered held down the Ctrl + Alt keys and pressed space. This restored the Content Assist function, but it required a brain remap when I am using one machine.

Answer (score 2):

!Screenshot of Eclipse Juno, I had the same problem, then I changed it to different key combination, then it works.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5uiB.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is what solved my problem.

Goto **Control Panel -> Clock, Language and Region -> Change keyboards or other input methods -> Change keyboards... -> Advanced Key Settings**. For some reason I had ctrl + space set as Key sequence for language hot keys. I changed them to something else and rebooted.

Make sure to reboot because it did not work for me without the reboot.

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu, Xfce, ctrl space was allocated to switch language on the iBus preferences (if you have this running, you will see the 'i' icon on the task bar, right click and choose preferences). To change this, bring up the **IBus Preferences**, on the General tab, see the "**Enable or disable:**" option, click the ellipses and provide a different keyboard assignment.

This sorted me out without need to restart Eclipse.

Comment: This only works if you don't need the iBus to enter chines and other characters.  If you do need them, you should have a solution which uses another character sequence in Eclipse for the same function.

Answer (score 1):

I use eclipse **indigo** and had this problem. Creating a new workspace did not worked.

Go to **Windows->preference->General->Keys->"Restore Default" - This fixed my issue**

Note that I just had English(US) on windows 7 [Control Panel-> Clock,Language and Region ->Change keyboard or other input methods-> Keyboards and Languages->change Keyboards...->General ==>Default language is English and Installed Services I just had English(US) alone

After doing this some you might need to restart the system if it does not fix.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed my problem on **Ubuntu 12.04** regardless of the eclipse version. My problem was that the ibus was overriding the shortcut so I deleted this shortcut configuration.

Type **ibus** in the dash:
[image: Search for ibus]

Then select **Keyboard Input Methods**. From there click on the first three dots next to the **Enable or disable** textfield. This windows should appear: [image: Shortcuts]

If there is something bound to **Ctrl + Space** simply delete it.

Comment: Million Thanks. It was indeed the ibus eating up ctrl+space.

Answer (score 0):

@Polac - Thx. That's what fixed it for me. I'd hit ctrl+space and I'd get a popup for chinese character selection. I have Windows 7 so for me it was: 
Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and Languages tab -> Change keyboards... button -> Advanced Key Settings tab

Be warned, its stubborn. I tried to just clear them, but as soon as I applied the settings they reset back to using the original key bindings. If I change the key binding to something obscure they still reset sometimes. It's annoying. Maybe its just my OS installation that's goofed, but it could be a Microsoft bug.

Didn't need Chinese on my system, so I removed it as an installed language in the first tab and that finally got rid of the hardcoded Chinese key bindings.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can use the **Alt-/** character sequense instead of **Control-Space**.  This is an old problem which Eclipse and Chinese keyboards, which they addressed by adding this short cut.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
***Windows / UV Elements - was OFF***! I don't know how but they were off. And when you click ***Ctrl+Space*** he working, but your all elements are off and you think that it is not working. You must on all UV elements and after your ***Ctrl + Space*** will be work.