# Ctrl + Space not working for content assist on eclipse

Tags: eclipse

My problem is that the content assist window won't pop up after clicking `Ctrl + Space`. I checked my shortcuts and the content assist is bound to `Ctrl + Space`. Sometimes the window automatically pops up making suggestion after typing dot e.g., but this won't happen when using the keys combination.

Eclipse version:

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>
> Version: Kepler Service Release 1 Build id: 20130919-0819

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 if that matters.

Comment: What development environment are you in? Java, CDT, PyDev?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ctrl Space Not Working in Eclipse Helios on Win 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509726/ctrl-space-not-working-in-eclipse-helios-on-win-7)

Comment: Also could be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358312/code-assist-ctrlspace-doesnt-work-on-eclipse-kepler?rq=1

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I managed to fix it finally. The problem was that the ibus was overriding the shortcut so I deleted this shortcut configuration.

Type **ibus** in the dash:
[image: Search for ibus]

Then select **Keyboard Input Methods**. From there click on the first three dots next to the **Enable or disable** textfield. This windows should appear: [image: Shortcuts]

If there is something bound to **Ctrl + Space** simply delete it.

Comment: I can confirm this fixed the same problem with a combination of Xubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse Luna 4.4.1. Very grateful, Ivaylo Toskov!

Comment: Thankyou ! This was driving me crazy !

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what caused my problem in XFCE. Just FYI The same dialog can be displayed by typing `ibus-setup` in terminal (source: http://nixnote.blogspot.de/2012/08/ctrlspace-content-assist-doesnt-work-in.html)

Answer (score 62):

In my case;
Window>Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced

Make sure Select the proposal>Template Proposals,SWT Template Proposals,Java Proposals ,Content assist cycling>Template Proposals,SWT Template Proposals,Java Proposals is ticked.

Comment: Thanks @devcelebi it solving my problems, In my eclipse setting does not selected Java Proposals.

Answer (score 47):

Go to Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced > select all Java only. If you select all, then multiple occurrence of same instance would be shown in Suggestion list. which might be annoying some times.

[image]

Comment: Its works fine for me. "Java Proposals" was suffice. I am using Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0). Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

For that  Go to

**Eclipse --> Windows --> Preferences --> Java --> Editor --> Content Assist --> Advanced --> select all Java & Java Type Proposals.**

and check mark : **Java Proposals(Code Recommenders)**

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks maaan

Answer (score 8):

To enable Ctrl+Space.

1. Go to Control Panel --> Region and Language --> select Keyboard and Languages tab --> Change Keyboard button --> select General tab --> Under Installed Services --> Remove all languages except English(United States). click apply and ok.
2. Eclipse --> Windows --> Preferences --> Java --> Editor --> Content Assist --> Advanced --> select all Java & Java Type Proposals.
3. Eclipse --> Windows --> Preferences --> General keys --> Type Content Assist in right side search box --> Select command Content Assist --> click on Restore To Default --> Apply --> ok

Now you are ready to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> feature for content assist.

Comment: Upvoted even if step 1 appears to be nonsense for someone using Ubuntu and not necessarily in US English, and step 3 doesn't appear to exist any more in Eclipse 6-19

Answer (score 8):

Earlier I was also facing the same issue : I just followed below steps :

1. Go to Windows --> Preferences --> Java --> Editor --> Content Assist --> Advanced --> select all Java & Java Type Proposals.
2. Click on Apply and close it.
3. Restart the eclipse.

[image]

Comment: yes, and you should do this for C,C++ editor as well if you use CDT and have that issue. The lists of proposal items to check is a bit smaller, but checking all of both lists solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

For **mac**:

By default **`ˆ+space`** is assigned for switching inputs of the keyboard.

You can deselect that option by going to

**System preference > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Input Sources**

check for shortcut that using your key and disable it

Comment: Thanks dude...!!! That was the reason for me too..

Comment: Así es.. esto funciona:
Deshabilitar el Ctrl + Space del sistema de Mac

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+space was  not working in my eclipse.Somehow it got disabled.

I have tried many options and didnt worked any options.

Finally this was work out

Go to Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > The "Auto activation triggers for Java:" field.
 Paste "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz." (note the dot after z) .This is the best solution and no need to  even press ctrl+space.

Comment: Best solution so far for me as I shifted to mac and nothing else worked.

Comment: If you really like the proposals dialog popping up with just about every key you type, then, sure, do this. I find it VERY annoying.
If you're just having trouble getting Ctrl-Space to work, see the other recommendations in this thread.
Also, check to make sure that you don't have other applications running that are using Ctrl-Space as a shortcut, as mentioned below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38090250/8517076

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me also,
What I have done is change the **workspace** folder to
Another folder and problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Though I have eclipse proposal settings configured properly it was not working for me. In my case Ctrl+space key combination was hijacked by another background running process (I was running AllwaysOnTop utility for windows). it worked after exit that process. :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me and none of the stack solutions seemed to resolve it. I finally figured that some other windows task was stealing my hotkey press. If nothing else works, I recommend that you downloaded a free software '[Windows Hotkey Explorer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Windows-Hotkey-Explorer.shtml)' that reported the registered hotkeys.

In my particular situation, I found ctrl+space was seized by 'blackboard collaborate' (a unpalatable java application for webcasts used by some of my courses).

I closed Eclipse killed all java processes (which included blackboard). Restarted eclipse and my autocomplete was back!

(Note: Hotkey Explorer was incredibly buggy and crashed every time I used it. I was able to get the information I needed before it crashed though so it was useful. Another (shareware) application that I didn't use but noticed online is: [Hotkey Commander](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. If you use OS X Eclipse Ctrl+Space shortcut can be interfering with OS X system's "Selecting previous input source" using Ctrl+Space shortcut as default.

It is necessary to edit System Preferencies/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Input Source and uncheck the "Selecting previous input source" or change the shortcut on something else. Eclipse should work after that even without restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it turned out that the Powertoys for Windows app suite overrides this shortcut for the "peek" utility. Solution: change the shortcut or disable the utility if you don't need it.

Comment: The question asker (OP) started that they are not using Windows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).