# ctrl+space has not working in MyEclipse 2021

Tags: java

I have tried following the instructions in the site, set up preference for Java shortcut, reboot, and even reinstall the version 2021. The shortcut keyboard is just not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm a Java dev and I would encourage you to switch to IntelliJ IDEA. If not possible, then try deleting the .metadata and redo your settings. When you reinstall Eclipse I think the .metadata folder isn't removed, and this could be a reason your reinstall might not fix the problem.

Comment: Have you already checked the suggestions in this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986750/ctrl-space-not-working-for-content-assist-on-eclipse

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen just trying to help OP

Comment: Are other things in the project working, like validation for instance? Not sure where you're starting from - did you create a new project in MyEclipse or did you import one? One problem could be that your project, if imported, isn't correctly detected as a Java project; do you get content assist if you create a new (dummy) Java project for testing? Happy to go deeper here or on the MyEclipse forums: https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topics/myeclipse/java-ee-development-ejb-jsp-struts-xdoclet-etc/