# Eclipse - show android classes with the key combination CTRL + Space while developing?

Tags: android, eclipse, preferences

I'am trying now to develop Android Apps using Eclipse. I have already installed the ADT Plugin and the Android SDK.

Now, I just want to see with the keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> the android classes(android packages) while typing a android method. For Example when i type `OnCr` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, it should show me the methods like `onCreate`, `onCreateContextMenu` and so on.But when i press these combination there comes `No Default Proposals` or something like that.

But if i type "ja" and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> it shows me all the java packages like java, java.awt and so on.

Or if i want to type for example System.out.println and just only type in System and press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> key i see that the System class is in the java.lang package and after a dought i can repeatly choose in the list a underclass of System class like out, in , getproperty and so on.

My question is what i must do in Eclipse so these function works for android packages or android classes whatever too?

I don't want ever type the full methodsnames to develop an application i want to choose it from the Proposals list. The own methods i have created are not a problem , i can see my own methods in the list but i  want to see the android methods too.

I have read in many communitys about Content Assist in Preferences section in Eclipse. But i can only tick there some standard things like java proposal or java non-type proposal how to add android?

Or a Suggestion in which another IDE i can do it with these lists for android is acceptable,too.

By the way i am using Eclipse Helios.

Can you help me please

Thx

HaShLo BuRn

Comment: Android uses the same classes as java. Whenever I work on an andorid project with eclipse I can always use ctrl space. I read your question 3 times and I don't see what is your problem Eclipse auto clompletion always worked fine for me

Comment: ok again, for example i want to write a public void onCreate Method. When i start to typing "onCrea" is it normal that the Proposal list don't appears? I think if i am typing the proposal list automatically must be shown or not? with the methods like onCreate or onCreateContextMenu or onCreateOptions Menu. In my IDE it don't appears this list. And i think you are wrong these Methods are not typical methods in java . These are only for android as far as i know. When i start to type "andr" the list must be shown and show me the packages like android or android.process or android.app and so on?

Comment: Question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working

Answer (score 1):

**Working solution:** I have deleted my Eclipse version. I had the `Eclipse for Java Developers` version and i replaced it with `Eclipse Classic 3.6.2`. I didn't have to reinstall the Android SDK.

Then I just install the ADT plugin in `Eclipse Classic` and link it with the Android SDK and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually starting from `onCr...` or are you doing `public void onCr...`?  The first will give you auto-complete proposals and the second will not.

Try the following simple example:

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;

public class AutoComplete extends Activity {
    onCr//CTRL-SPACE here
}
```

This shows the list of suggestions fine for me in Eclipse 3.4.2 with no additional configuration.

Comment: i start typing like the first one but no result , if i start tyoing like the second one i don't get a result, too.

Comment: I have upload an image of my IDE while typing the example: Image Link:http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/8626/eclipsed.png how can i fix this please help. In this topic: http://androidforums.com/developer-101/101413-type-ahead-autocomplete-eclipse.html there is the same problem , the user there use Netbeans instead of Eclipse but it must be possible in Eclipse. I don't wanna change my IDE just because it don't show the list with the examples ... PLEASE HELP