# Eclipse Template Proposals (aka auto completion) not working

Tags: java, eclipse

recently the proposals (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) for Eclipse/Java stopped working, as suggested in the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working) I looked at the **Preferences** of **Content Assist** for **Java**, but all options are checked and still not working, any idea?

EDIT: One error is shown while trying to display proposals: `Project facet grails.app has not been defined. It is used in plugin com.springsource.sts.server.tc.core.`

Comment: Hmm... things usually don't stop working spontaneously... did you change any settings recently? Install any updates? Remove any plugins?

Comment: No changes where made, except importing a Project from SVN, but I don't think it has anything to do with the problem, has it?

Comment: Try [cleaning Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/).

Comment: Does the Eclipse error log provide any information ?

Comment: Cleaning Eclipse won't work... I'll see the error log now

Comment: One error is shown while trying to display proposals: Project facet grails.app has not been defined. It is used in plugin com.springsource.sts.server.tc.core.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Somehow the references to the JDK where broken, so no completions could be made!

**UPDATE:** Solved by going to `Window -> Preferences -> Installed JREs` and changing the JDK folder to the right one.

Comment: How did you fix the problem?