# How to setup eclipse content assist with Android and Java or any other language?

Tags: android, eclipse, content-assist

does anyone know what you have to do to get content assist working in Eclipse? Do you have to point to some file or folder maybe. I have checked in preferences and all those proposal tick boxes are checked so that isn't the problem and control_space brings up the content assist box but it says there are no default proposals. It did work for me with android until a couple weeks ago when I changed something or updated software but I can't remember what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem a couple of weeks ago. And I followed [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/content-assist-ctrl-space-is-not-working-eclipse/) blog and [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-content-assist.htm) documentation.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to **restore your defaults** under `Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced` as suggested in [another, quite popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/908930/95033). Even if all checkboxes are checked there might be some kind of conflict going on.

Comment: Nope, no luck trying that. Thanks anyway