# No Default Proposals in Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse

I switched to Eclipse Juno for android development recently.When I press "ctrl+space" to see available proposals.But it shows "No Default Proposals".

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with android development. I'm developing for plain Java and had the same issue.

Comment: Restoring the Defaults didn't work for me. But after I Closed and Opened the Android Project, the Proposals showed up again.

Answer (score 95):

I have the same problem; it occurred after I upgraded to Juno.

My fix:
- Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced
- explicitly check Java Proposals
- Apply

That fixed it for me. (I don't know why Restore Defaults does not set this, seems like it should but it didn't work for me)

Comment: It's Window->Preferences->Java-> **Editor** ->Content Assist->Advanced for me but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Second issue I got with eclipse Juno this week - also had http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340653/console-disappear-in-eclipse-juno

Comment: the option doesn't stay selected and the issue isn't fixed unfortunately. every time I bring up the option again the "Java Proposals" is unchecked.

Answer (score 9):

Try restoring the `Restore Default` options in

`Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced > Restore Default`

See image clearly at below.

[image: Eclipse Image]

For more, have a look on

1. [Eclipse/Java code completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working).
2. [Content Assist (Ctrl + Space) Is Not Working – Eclipse](http://www.mkyong.com/java/content-assist-ctrl-space-is-not-working-eclipse/)

Hope it helps you.!!

Answer (score 3):

Simply do a Project> Clean and then restart Eclipse. I had the same issue

Comment: helped me and easy solution

Answer (score 2):

Change workspace and try it now. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

be sure your are in a java Perspective and that your project is reconized as an Android project maybe

Comment: I developed project in Android perspective only

Comment: - have you restarted eclipse?

Comment: - otherwise, doing that in eclipse : Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor ->Content Assist Advanced -> Restore Defaults

Comment: - or restart eclipse with "-clean" parameter

Comment: In  Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor ,I am not able to find "Content Assist Advanced". I also restarted eclipse but problem not resolved

Comment: @user915267 I think @Rocel meant `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced` (note that `Advanced` is another level in hierachy. I have a fresh install of `Juno` and I was able to find it. In there I have only `Java Proposals` checked in upper list. BTW: If you have trouble finding options in *Eclipse* manually, you can always use search box (upper left corner of `Preferences`).

Answer (score 0):

We can change the settings as per our requirement.

Suppose we want to make **java proposal** as highest priority we need to do changes as shown below.

<kbd>Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Java</kbd> > <kbd>Editor</kbd> > <kbd>Content Assist</kbd> > <kbd>Advanced</kbd>

Choose <kbd>java proposal</kbd> and click on <kbd>up</kbd> button
[image]