# Console disappear in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, console, eclipse-juno

I am using Eclipse Juno. I was working in **Java perspective** and suddenly I minimized the console. I don't know where it went but I am unable to get it back. I even tried to get it from Windows>Show View>Console but I didn't get my console back.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

It happened the same thing to me. Just click Window->Reset Perspective and everything will be back as it was when you installed eclipse.
Sure you'll have to customize it back to how you like it, but at least you'll have the console back.

Comment: Worked for me, with Eclipse Luna.

Comment: THanks. Works with Jee Mars too

Comment: Worked with Neon (4.6) too.

Comment: this works but it doesn't prevent the problem from occurring again, unfortunately.

Comment: worked with oxygen too, just closed the perspective and reopen it.

Answer (score 21):

If console is not visible, just search for "Console" in QuickAccess box on the right hand top of menu bar. you can get it back!

Comment: This is the preferred method over the accepted answer, as it doesn't reset your perspective.

Comment: This doesn't always work.  Sometimes the window does seem to fully disappear.  Worthy trying before resting the perspective and needing to set it up again.

Comment: actually, the accepted answer did not work for me, but this one did in Luna

Answer (score 7):

Stupid Eclipse. Are there no interface designers volunteering on this project?  Why minimize something and make it hard to see where to bring it back?  Probably all you have to do is hit Shift-Control-Tab-F9 with one hand while right-double-clicking the lower left hand corner.  Hmm, how about a popup when you click a minimized Console that says "We see you've minimized your Console and you are clearly trying to switch to it.  Would you like us to restore that so you can actually see it?" followed by "Are you really sure? Cuz ya know, you may be using this click path by accident."

The reset perspective works.  Also, you can "Save Perspective" so it's not so hard to go back to your preferred Perspective.

Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

1. Bring console to the front from Window -> Show View -> Console. Apparently the console remains invisible (that was the issue indeed), but it is virtually active in the foreground.
2. Close the current view (i.e. the invisible console) by going to the "Quick Access" box at the toolbar, typing "Close Part", and selecting the respective option on the drop-down.
3. Reopen console form Window -> Show View -> Console and voilà, it will appear. Drag it to your preferred location on the workbench.

This works for me under the following situation:

- I had been previously playing with detaching several views (console included) and editors to a separate window on a different monitor; I have updated my workspace from Neon to Oxygen and I have had a hard reset at my computer. (So, not sure which among those was the reason that made it go wrong).
- I wanted to avoid resetting my perspective, as it is highly customised, so I discarded that solution.
- Other solutions herein proposed had not worked.
- The console was working and the view became visible if I chose a different perspective (e.g. Debug) or a duplicate Eclipse window (which effectively provides a duplicate of a factory-reset perspective).

Answer (score 0):

you could click the small icon on the bottom left and choose console. it will appear.

Comment: It didn't work for me either. I Right Clicked the Java Perspective and Clicked on 'Reset' to reset to all the default configurations.