# Eclipse Autocomplete Java Missing

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk, prediction

Automcomplete in eclipse has stopped working. How do I re enable this?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "autocomplete" or "content assist". Try searching for "eclipse autocomplete not working" on a search engine of your choice.

Comment: There are [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working) and [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746294/eclipse-autocomplete-not-working) of [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653448/no-default-proposals-in-eclipse-juno) on this [topic](http://superuser.com/questions/209752/eclipse-doesnt-autocomplete-and-find-references-anymore).  Can you be more specific about what, if anything, you've already tried to fix this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912169/eclipse-enable-autocomplete-content-assist

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy Turner and everyone who answered, I've already found the answer of this problem. restoring the default options in 'Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced'