# Suggestion about Attribute and Method not coming in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing android application in eclipse. I am new to it. But when press dot(.) after a class-instance, no pop-up menu is coming, showing suggestions and attributes.
I am attaching a screenshot.[image]

Comment: Did you try Ctrl + SpaceBar?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try restoring the default options in 'Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced'.

You can find you answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/908930/1298796).

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I will select the answer after the 6 minutes bar.

Comment: The thing which you want to do is called as "Intellisense". Displays the properties after a dot(.)

Answer (score 0):

you should go here first. 'Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist.
then write this code under the auto activation trigger for java.: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._`
then it work...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmXwG.png)