# Eclipse "Show Proposal" key combination not working for Java or C

Tags: java, c, eclipse

I recently downloaded Eclipse, and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, it does not show any proposal.

For example, if I have a variable named `TotalElements` and in another place in the code, when I type `Tota` and then press ctrl-space it should propose `TotalElements`.  However, it does not do this.

I have gone to windows -> preferences > java -> editor -> advance.  I have everything checked, and it still does not work.

Am I missing some plugins?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a similar problem, but it happens only when I open the Android Plugin and run an Android app. After that, the "Show Proposal" is not shown anymore and I have to restart my computer. Do you have the Android Plugin installed too?

Comment: No i dont have the android plugin install. I search the web a lot to solve that issue, since it allows me to program much faster. But so far no luck

Comment: Did you find this post too? [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working)

Comment: yeah i did. still it does not work.

Comment: @Alessandroempire Did you resolve it? Because i don't...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this is to change the key binding.

In Preferences, select the *General>Keys* page. Search for the "Content Assist" command. In the *Binding* field, delete the existing binding, and press control-Tab. You should see "Ctrl+Tab". Press the *Apply* button.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure that your using correct explorer. 
Below is the reference image for you. If 'J' icon is hollow than no proposal will display.
 [image]