# Eclipse content assist stopped working properly

Tags: eclipse, ide, content-assist

When I press CTRL+SPACE I get suggestions from the file i'm working on only.

I've tried the solution offered here: [Eclipse/Java code completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working)

i.e. going to `Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced` and restoring defaults, and indeed there are some things getting rechecked, I click apply, but as soon as I press CTRL+SPACE again the things get unchecked again...

I've even tried downloading a new copy of eclipse specifying a new workspase and opening a new project, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

please check you system hot key settings. is there a system level hot key binding to "CTRL+SPACE", or you can change the Content Assist key to test is verything ok?

Comment: you can set the key bind in Preference - Keys page.

Comment: CTRL+SPACE pops up the content assist window, it just does not offer all the options it should. Eclipse recognizes the key shortcut, but the content assist is not working properly.

Comment: Does the eclipse give you any information when you press the hot key?

Comment: yes, i get content assist for the file i'm in, methods and variables in the class i'm working in, for example if i type 'new ' and then CTRL+SPACE it wold inevitably complete the class name, as it is the only class it knows

Comment: a list of all possible classes

Comment: when i say "it wold inevitably complete the class name" i mean it would put down the name of the class i'm in