# How to cancel tip in eclipse pydev?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I use eclipse and pydev, I have canceled the tips by using

1. perferences-general-editors-text editor-annotation: error, spelling errors and warning
2. perferences-pydev-editor: hover, and  code analysis(including undefined)
3. Preferences->Java->Editor->Hovers--Combined Hover

But when cursor stay on some function names, there's still a prompt box: `"Undefined variable:function-name  press f2 for focus".`

Could anyone please tell me how to cancel these tips ?

Comment: Maybe you need to reverse the steps from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/908489/622391)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your use case? (it's a bit hard knowing which tip is being shown just from the description).