# Code completion for OpenCV in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I am using OpenCV for Java and have installed it according to the tutorial found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html#java-eclipse). However, in Eclipse, there seems to be no code completion available. Are there any extra steps required for this or is code completion simply not available?

Comment: Are you sure you've added the binary jar (and not a source jar) to your project? That's all that should be necessary.

Comment: In the tutorial above there is no mentioning of any such step being necessary. For Windows, it seems that the binaries are already built and just need to be imported. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not OpenCV itself, but rather the fresh Eclipse distribution that I downloaded. Code completion (Ctrl + Space) was not working for anything, not just OpenCV. The solution can be found here: [Eclipse/Java code completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working).