# Eclipse code completion for member-names

Tags: eclipse, code-completion, variable-declaration

When I type

```
private SomeClass s
```

and hit CRTL+SPACE I usually got suggestions from code completion like

```
private SomeClass someClass;
```

Now that i use JBossDevStudio 8.0.0 it doesn't work anymore. I just get some useless suggestions like JPATemplates and stuff.

Does anybody know how to configure this correct?

Comment: Google reveals this link (https://developer.jboss.org/thread/228432), which suggests your problem is not unique and is solved by following:

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advance

Check Java Type Proposals.

Comment: Thx a lot, i didn't found it on google.

Comment: Did it work? If so - I'll put it in an answer.

Comment: Yes, it does work nicely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse/Java code completion not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working)