# HashMap in Java Eclipse Proposals Window

Tags: java, eclipse, hashmap

I am using Indigo Eclipse for Java as a beginner user. When I press Ctrl+Space to select from the proposal window for HashMap it does not show anything. I did import the library and I did select the Java Proposals from the reference window. What do I do to fix this little problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse/Java code completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working)

This is what you're looking for. I guess the developers called this a proposal window but Microsoft has always called it intellisense I believe.