# Autocomplete in Eclipse plug in?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have recently started using Eclipse for work after being taught coding in university IntelliJ.

One feature that IntelliJ has was that it had the autocomplete feature when coding for example pressing 'p' gave a drop down menu of public, private and protected (to name a few).

Eclipse doesnt seem to have this feature, or does it? Is there a plug in that enables Eclipse to add this in?

Any help/advice please.

Comment: You have to trigger autocompletion by pressing Ctrl+Space, then you are presented the alternatives, including public, private, etc (when in the right scope). If you want it to appear sooner, try playing around with Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Auto Activation.

Comment: it has, you can try it.Ctrl+Space or .(dot). you get that autocomplete

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/209752/eclipse-doesnt-autocomplete-and-find-references-anymore  see this link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working see this link too.                                                  2. Content Assist Configuration
Configure Eclipse’s content assist, go “Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced“. Make sure “Other Java Proposals” is ticked