# Navigating options are not working in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

After long time i was working today on Selenium webdriver and i observed that navigating options arent working in Selenium.
I am woring in WIN10
I tried with all jar files, 2.53,3.01 with geckodriver. 
Example: driver. is not displaying any autocomplete options and also it is throwing error if typed manually.

Also i observed a strange behaviour that, navigating options are working in my previously created project class file and if i create another class inside same project, navigating options or autocomplete options are not displayed and not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zPOK.jpg)

Comment: This may be problem with your eclipse configuration. you check here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working

Comment: @rajesh.h.sraj How does it relates to #selenium tag or #selenium-webdriver tag? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issues occur related to .jar file which you have imported in your Eclipse ide. so you can use the project clean option
Project->clean

OR

You can remove the imported .jar file from your build path and reimport it again