# Eclipse content assist not working in enum constant parameter list

Tags: java, eclipse

Using eclipse, when I enter the following:

```
public enum Foo {
    A(Integer.);
    private final Integer integer;

    private Foo(Integer integer) {
        this.integer = integer;
    }
}
```

And position my cursor after `Integer.` and ask for content assist (^space) I get nothing. In fact content assist does not seem to work at all inside enum constant argument lists.

Is this a known problem or expected behaviour? If the latter, why?

EDIT: I'm wondering if this is a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=395604

If so I'm amazed that such an obvious thing hasn't been fixed in the past 5 years with the number of Java developers using Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right, it is a **known bug** or at least a missing feature of the Eclipse Java IDE:

[**Eclipse Bug 395604 - Code assist does not work after anonymous class inside in an array initializer**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=395604)

In the last 5 years, there have been only a few votes for this bug and also only very few comments, so it doesn't seem to be particularly important for most users. I voted for the bug and added a comment with a link to your question. Eclipse is open source and the bug is tagged with `helpwanted`. So any Java developer is welcome to make Eclipse a little bit better by implementing this.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I will have a shot at fixing it myself.

Comment: @sprinter That would be super cool! There is a similar bug that has been fixed recently: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526590

Comment: Truely amazing, in Enums this is so annoying!

Comment: So this hasn't been fixed yet? @sprinter no luck?

Comment: @AgentM Nope. I had a go at fixing it but found understanding the eclipse code in this area incredibly time consuming so eventually gave up. To be honest I gave up on eclipse altogether and moved to intellij not long after this question. This was one of several bugs in eclipse that I found incredibly annoying for Java and unfixed for a long period.