# Eclipse content assist auto complete not working even with the settings

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I am having issues with the content assist, I tried to fix it by going to the preference->java->content assist and check the auto complete, I also put the suggested triggers "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._@." still doesn't work
This is what it shows instead of autocomplete suggestions. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN43c.png)
When I do press the ctrl+space things it just moves to show swt proposals or others.

I cannot see the suggestions but the enter key puts in the first suggestion.

Comment: Is there anything reported in the error log when this happens?

Comment: This might be the answer you are looking for [stackOverflowQA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem fixed which wasn't really a problem. My content assist was just minimized and looked like a bar, i just had to pull it to bigger size.