# Eclipse proposals don't show every completion possible

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, new-operator

solved

I was running this simple code and it worked:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Display extends JFrame{
    Display(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

When I go inside eclipe and type this.setV then ctrl + space I was expecting to see setVisible() to show up but it doesnt. If I wrote this.set then ctrl+space I can see plenty of proposals.

I tried to go into preference > java > editor > content assist > advanced and check every boxes but it doesn't fix it. The code works, I am able to generator a 500x500 window but because I'm beggining in java I think it would be helpful to have all proposals when I hit ctrl + space.
I have seen videos on youtube of people using eclipse and being able to see the .setVisible() in the proposals so I have no idea of why this happens.

I'm using  eclipse IDE version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)
JavaSE-16
windows 10

Thank you for any advice !

Comment: have you tried answers in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working

Comment: Thank you this answer solved it !
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27817538/17196377
I never saw this question when I searched it sorry for the inconveniance!